# Youtube-dl fails on youtube and works on other sites

Tags: wildcards, youtube-dl, youtube

I started having this issue a few days ago: `youtube-dl` no longer works for links to YouTube, but works fine for other sites such as Instagram:

```
$ youtube-dl https://www.instagram.com/p/B47c667AKPo/
[Instagram] B47c667AKPo: Downloading webpage
[download] Destination: Video by marieforleo-B47c667AKPo.mp4
[download]   2.5% of 40.44MiB at  1.45MiB/s ETA 00:27^C
...

$ youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blHgexdxfVU
Usage: youtube-dl [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]

youtube-dl: error: You must provide at least one URL.
Type youtube-dl --help to see a list of all options.
```

Ignoring HTTPS certificates with an HTTP address or [a `--no-check-certificate`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337958/error-downloading-youtube-video-using-youtube-dl) also fails. The same YouTube link and syntax worked a few weeks ago.

I upgraded to the latest version, `2020.03.01`, and still have the same issue.

Is anything the matter between YouTube and `youtube-dl`?

Comment: To see if/how the shell modifies your URL because of the `?` you can use e.g. `( set -x ; youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blHgexdxfVU )`.

Comment: It's very weird: the same command on the same system was working the day after. Could some shell environment variable cause the `?` to expand?

Comment: Currently it is not even clear if a wildcard expansion is really the cause of your problem. The behavior may depend on the shell you are using and on the specific URL and the files that exist on your system. Did you try with exactly the same command, i.e. the same URL the day after? Did you remove files from your system? If you can reproduce the problem, please run the command from my previous comment and show its output in the question.

Comment: I am using `bash`. Yes, I tried exactly the same command saved in my bash history. I did change user files on my system but no system files that I can remember. Can you post an answer and I'll close this for now, then if I get the same problem I'll run your commands and post an update.

Comment: There is already an answer that proposes to quote the argument to avoid possible expansion/globbing by the shell. Without more information we cannot prove that this was the cause for your problem.

Comment: @Bodo OK, I'll accept that answer for now and then revive the thread with more information if I run into the same problem again.

Comment: Upon reading the manual with `youtube-dl --help`, I will use `-g` (Simulate, quiet but print URL), `-v` (Print various debugging information), and `--write-pages` (Write downloaded intermediary pages to files in the current directory to debug problems) to debug next time I have a problem.

Comment: I guess the debug options provided by `youtube-dl` will not help. As shown in the question it displayed an error message `error: You must provide at least one URL.`. Apparently it didn't find a URL in the command line arguments. I suggest to (additionally) use `set -x` as I wrote in my first comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your shell is trying to expand the wildcard character `?`. Surround the URL with single quotes to disable all expansion:

```
youtube-dl 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoid'
```